# Generate 3 random float numbers between min and max with specific float mean in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random

I need to generate 3 random float numbers (with exactly 2 digit after point) with the specific average between specific range.

For example:

I want the mean to be 37.14. My min is 31 and my max in 42. So I want to generate 3 random numbers within that range which give me the mean I want like:

41.35 ,
37.31 ,
32.77

I came accross the following code but it does generate integer.

```
n = 3;
xmean = 37;
xmin = 31;
xmax = 42;
xeps = 0.01;
x = randi([xmin xmax],n,1);
while abs(xmean - mean(x)) >= xeps
    if xmean > mean(x)
        x(find(x < xmean,1)) = randi([xmean xmax]);
    elseif xmean < mean(x)
        x(find(x > xmean,1)) = randi([xmin xmean]);
    end
end
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `randi` by `rand`:

```
n = 3;
xmean = 37;
xmin = 31;
xmax = 42;
xeps = 0.01;
x = 0.01*round(100*(xmin+(xmax-xmin)*rand(n,1)));
while abs(xmean - mean(x)) >= xeps
    if xmean > mean(x)
        x(find(x < xmean,1)) = 0.01*round(100*(xmean+(xmax-xmean)*rand(1)));
    elseif xmean < mean(x)
        x(find(x > xmean,1)) = 0.01*round(100*(xmin+(xmean-xmin)*rand(1)));
    end
end
```

Comment: That was simple. Thanks for the answer. But still it produce the random numbers with more than 2 floating points.37.1458242086426
41.4951011679625
32.7598491878108

Comment: I edited it with the rounding. You should be able to use `round2(x, 0.01)` if it makes it clearer than `0.01*round(x*100)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to multiply xmin xmean xmax by 100. Then divide the result by 100:

```
n = 3;
xmean = 37;
xmin = 31;
xmax = 42;
xeps = 0.01;

xmin = xmin*100;
xmax = xmax*100;
xmean = xmean*100;

x = randi([xmin xmax],n,1);
while abs(xmean - mean(x)) >= xeps
    if xmean > mean(x)
        x(find(x < xmean,1)) = randi([xmean xmax]);
    elseif xmean < mean(x)
        x(find(x > xmean,1)) = randi([xmin xmean]);
    end
end
x = x .* 0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraint, only two of the three random numbers can be chosen freely. Thus, you can draw two numbers in the range and calculate the third one. Since the constraint is the mean, you know at least one number has to be larger than the mean and one has to be smaller than the mean to reduce the number of iterations till you find a solution that satisfies the range.

```
xmean = 37;
xmin = 31;
xmax = 42;

% scale for easier rounding to two digits
xmin = xmin*100;
xmax = xmax*100;
xmean = xmean*100;

foundSolution = false;
x = Nan(1,3);


while ~foundSolution
x(1) = randi([xmin,xmean]);
x(2) = randi([xmean,xmax]);
x(3) = 3*xmean-sum(x(1:2));

if x(3) >= xmin && x(3) <= xmax
   foundSolution = true;
end
end

%# rescale back
x = x/100;
```